# Does upvoting a duplicate comment do anything?

Tags: support, comments, duplicate-questions, up-votes

When a question is initially flagged as a duplicate, there is a comment. If the duplicate flag gets enough votes, the question is closed as a duplicate, and the comment is deleted.  Does upvoting the duplicate comment count as a close vote? Does it do anything at all?

Comment: It makes the comment more likely to be shown than other comments in the event that some of the comments need to be hidden.  That, and displaying a number for people to see, is the only effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it just counts as another upvote on the comment (it increases the vote count).

Additional "close as exact duplicate flags" will also increase the vote count on a "possible duplicate" comment (if it exists).  But the comment score itself has no effect on closing a question.

Comment: As a sidenote: I've noticed recently that voting for the duplicate doesn't upvote the related comment anymore. Is this a conscious change?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I'm not quite sure how that works.  If someone manually posts as "possible duplicate" comment (instead of the automagically posted comment), I would imagine that the system may not be aware of it.